# How do I deduplicate observations but keeping the row with the most information in SAS

Tags: sas, duplicates

I have a data set with 170 columns and 2000 rows.  Many of the observations are exact duplicates or similar. My data are in the following form:

```
   A          B        C      D  
 Entry 1   Florida     .     54
 Entry 1      .        .     54
 Entry 1   Florida     .     54
 Entry 1   Florida    New     .
 Entry 1   Florida    New    54
```

As you will notice, column A is always populated.  I want to deduplicate these so that I only return

```
    A         B        C       D
  Entry 1   Florida    New       54
```

Any suggestions of how to do this in SAS?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want it in that specific format with C missing, or do you want to find all rows where A,B,C,D has the most information? Basically we need to define what "information," is to know which is the most important row to keep. Are some columns more important than others, and provide more information than others?

Comment: Sorry, My mistake, I have edited my desired output.  I'd like to return a value for every column

Comment: Please remember to include anything you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

This will give the last non-missing value for each level of A.

```
data have;
   input (A  B  C)(&$) D;
   cards; 
 Entry 1   Florida     .     54
 Entry 1      .        .     54
 Entry 1   Florida     .     54
 Entry 1   Florida    New     .
 Entry 1   Florida    New    54
 ;;;;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
data want;
   update have(obs=0) have;
   by a;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]

Comment: I love this idea. Well done. Update automatically doesn't replace missing values, making this a very efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assume in this case that all information is equally weighted, and your primary key is A. We will count the number of missing values for A and only keep the row with the least number of missing values. The row with the least number of missing values gives you the highest amount of information for each value of primary key A.

```
proc sort data=have;
    by A;
run;

data count_info;
    set have;
    by A;

    info_count = cmiss(of _ALL_);
run;

proc sort data=count_info;
    by A info_count;
run;

data want;
    set count_info;
    by A info_count;

    if(first.A);
run;
```